# Change <select>'s option and trigger events with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select, dom-events

How can I change an HTML `<select>`'s option with JavaScript (without any libraries like jQuery), while triggering the same events as if a user had made the change?

For example using following code, if I change the option with my mouse then an event triggers (i.e. `onchange` is run). However, when I change the option using JavaScript then it doesn't fire any event. Is it possible to fire trigger associated event handlers like `onclick`, `onchange`, etc., when an option is selected with JavaScript?

```
<select id="sel" onchange='alert("changed")'>
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("sel").options[1].selected = true;' value="Change option to 2" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xwywvd1a/

Comment: But y do you want to trigger onchange  event? You can do same stuff where you are selecting  the option..

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to manually fire the `change` event. And using the [Event Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) will be the best solution.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#sel'),
    input = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
select.addEventListener('change',function(){
    alert('changed');
});
input.addEventListener('click',function(){
    select.value = 2;
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

```html
<select id="sel" onchange='alert("changed")'>
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3' selected>Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Change option to 2" />
```

And, of course, the `Event` constructor is not supported in IE. So you may need to polyfill with this:

```
function Event( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
}
```

Comment: what if i again select the same option. It does not fire the change event again.

Comment: If i run $('#sel').val('3'); it will not get fire. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: For React developers, you must use new Event('input', { bubbles: true }).  the bubbles: true is essential to propagate the event to React's event handling layer.

Comment: The `alert` is a blocking function. Instead try using `console.log`.

Answer (score 26):

Fiddle of my solution is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7fqr428m/). But just in case it expires I will paste the code as well.

HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Change option to 2" />
```

JS:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel'),
    button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    sel.options[1].selected = true;

    // firing the event properly according to StackOverflow
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually
    if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
        sel.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    else {
        sel.fireEvent("onchange");
    }
});

sel.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: Additionally: ```button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    sel.options[1].selected = true;
    /*since ie9 this is possible, for ie8 and below you need to add some hacks*/
    sel.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent('change') );
});```

Comment: Thanks Karol "createEvent" path in Angular also works for IE11 :-)

Answer (score 23):

It is as simple as this:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    sel.options[1].selected = true;
    sel.onchange();
});
```

But this way has a problem. You can't call events just like you would, with normal functions, because there may be more than one function listening for an event, and they can get set in several different ways.

Unfortunately, the 'right way' to fire an event is not so easy because you have to do it differently in Internet Explorer (using document.createEventObject) and Firefox (using document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"))

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    sel.options[1].selected = true;
    fireEvent(sel,'change');

});


function fireEvent(element,event){
    if (document.createEventObject){
    // dispatch for IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Comment: was having this issue in react / electron. The last part of this answer was the only fix that worked for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The whole creating and dispatching events works, but since you are using the `onchange` attribute, your life can be a little simpler:

http://jsfiddle.net/xwywvd1a/3/

```
var selEl = document.getElementById("sel");
selEl.options[1].selected = true;
selEl.onchange();
```

If you use the browser's event API (addEventListener, IE's AttachEvent, etc), then you will need to create and dispatch events as others have pointed out already.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<select id="sel">
 <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option> 
  <option value='3'>Three</option> 
  </select> 


  <input type="button" value="Change option to 2"  onclick="changeOpt()"/>

  <script>

  function changeOpt(){
  document.getElementById("sel").options[1].selected = true;

alert("changed")
  }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

These questions may be relevant to what you're asking for:

- [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)
- [How to trigger an event in an input field changed with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227502/how-to-trigger-an-event-in-an-input-field-changed-with-javascript?rq=1)

Here are my thoughts: You can stack up more than one call in your onclick event like this:

```
<select id="sel" onchange='alert("changed")'>
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("sel").options[1].selected = true; alert("changed");' value="Change option to 2" />
```

You could also call a function to do this.

If you really want to call one function and have both behave the same way, I think something like this should work. It doesn't really follow the best practice of "Functions should do one thing and do it well", but it does allow you to call one function to handle both ways of changing the dropdown. Basically I pass (value) on the onchange event and (null, index of option) on the onclick event.

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/mmaynar1/pen/ZYJaaj

```
<select id="sel" onchange='doThisOnChange(this.value)'>
<option value='1'>One</option>
<option value='2'>Two</option>
<option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick='doThisOnChange(null,1);' value="Change option to 2"/>

<script>
doThisOnChange = function( value, optionIndex)
{
    if ( optionIndex != null )
    {
       var option = document.getElementById( "sel" ).options[optionIndex];
       option.selected = true;
       value = option.value;
    }
    alert( "Do something with the value: " + value );
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is another fake solution. What if someone attached a lot of handlers to `onchange` on `select` element? How will this construction work? The one thing for sure is that it will not trigger any of them...

Answer (score 1):

**html using Razor:**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("test1", Model.SelectOptionList, new { id = "test1", onchange = "myFunction()" })
```

**JS Code:**

```
function myFunction() {

            var value = document.getElementById('test1').value;

            console.log("it has been changed! to " + value );
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can fire the event manually after changing the selected option on the onclick event doing: `document.getElementById("sel").onchange();`

Comment: This works (with some limitations) only when `onchange` property has been set, not with inline handlers.

Comment: document.getElementById(...).onchange is not a function if there is no inline handlers.