# HTML select form - how to "trigger" default option

Tags: jquery, html, forms, onchange

I have found lots of useful examples of how to set up a HTML "select" form. What I can not find anywhere, is how to "auto-trigger" the default option, without having to "select" it first from drop-down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change <select>'s option and trigger events with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329978/change-selects-option-and-trigger-events-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already defined `onchange` event for `select` element, you can call `.onchange()` to trigger `onchange` event of the `select` element.

Sample code below:

```html
<form>
 <select name="fruit" onchange="showFruit(this.value)">
  <option>Choice:</option>    
  <option value="1">Yellow Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Red Fruit</option>
 </select>
</form>

<script>
 window.onload = function () {
  var el = document.getElementsByName('fruit')[0];
  el.value = 1; //Set default value
  el.onchange(); //trigger onchange event
 }

 function showFruit(val) {
  alert(val);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: `window.onload` is JavaScript and you need to include all the code above inside `<script></script>` tags. Updated code above.

Comment: It works, Phani!! Absolutely perfect!! Thank you very much! Will mark this as accepted! And also thank you to HBK for the previous answer!

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the `onload()` method:

```
Var select = document.getElementsByName('fruit')[0];
select.value=1;
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

This shall change the selected option to `1` (or any other as you would like) on page load and also fire the `onchange` event which shall populate your table.

Comment: @butterfly here you go... https://mobile.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm . Although I would suggest you brush up your JavaScript basics knowledge a bit. Regards.

Comment: As soon as I accumulate my 15 reputation points, will do! :-) Thanks again! :-)