# how to trigger click event on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to click the option something like this..

**JS**

```
$("#practice-area optgroup option").click(function(){
// code function here
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="practice-area" id="practice-area">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <optgroup label="NSW">
        <option value="1397">Armidale</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="NT">
        <option value="1402">Darwin</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change <select>'s option and trigger events with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329978/change-selects-option-and-trigger-events-with-javascript)

Comment: You should use "change" as oppose to "click"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `change` event handler on `select` not the `option`.

`option` doesn't have a `click` event handler, so you can get the `option` selected by the `select` using `$('select :selected')` or `$('select option:selected')`

```js
$("#practice-area").click(function(){
  // do what you want when you click select
  console.log('select clicked');
});

// normally use change
$("#practice-area").change(function(){
  console.log('change to ' + $(this).find(':selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="practice-area" id="practice-area">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <optgroup label="NSW">
        <option value="1397">Armidale</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="NT">
        <option value="1402">Darwin</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```