# How do I replace select content on web page with vb.net

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, html-agility-pack, cefsharp

I only want to show rank 1 pokemon. i am able to replace combobox with my code. but rank 1 pokemon are not coming. How should I solve this?
I am using htmlagilitypack, cefsharp and vb.net. this is the code i use

`_browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName('form-control col-3 col-sm-2')[1].selectedIndex = '1';})();")`

The content of the combobox changes but does not affect the page. I couldn't figure out what to do. I tried all the codes. but dont work.
[image: i dont change pokemons]

i want only rank 1 pokemons (#1)

[image: i want it]

Comment: Run your JavaScript in DevTools, make sure it's working see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging if it works in DevTools then your probably executing the JavaScript to early, before the DOM has been updated.

Comment: hi master;
how i try it? im new programmer. this code is opera browser. when i chose rank1 then its code

`<select class="form-control col-3 col-sm-2" style="z-index: unset;">
<option value="all">All</option>
<option value="1">#1</option>
<option value="2to10">#2 to #10</option>
<option value="11to20">#11 to #20</option>
</select>`

Comment: Open Devtools and execute your JavaScript in the console.

Comment: i write this code. its work again but didnt show rank 1 pokemons. why ?
`(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName('form-control col-3 col-sm-2')[1].selectedIndex = '1';})();`

this site is https://pokehubcoordinates.com/pvp

Comment: What do you mean it works again? You'll need to debug this yourself.

Comment: I am changing "select"-"option" on the site with this code I wrote. But it doesn't affect pokemon.

Comment: Open the site in Chrome, open DevTools, get your JavaScript working there. Start with the basics, confirm you have the correct html element.

Comment: my code is modifying the data in the combobox. so "#1" comes instead of "all". The html element I wrote is correct, but the pokemon don't change. same condition as above picture.

Comment: Maybe you need generate change event by yourself. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324400/18452174