# Select option is not working when using Karate UI select?

Tags: karate

I tried this `Given select('select[name=data1]', '{}Option Two')` for selecting the dropdown select. I can see the changes in the select tag, but when click the submit button, it resetted to the default option.

I both tried these solutions. Don't work.

`* def envName = 'env-rab'` 
`* select('#environmentId', envName)`

`* script("document.getElementById('environmentId').value='" + env-rab + "'")`

**EDIT:**

Change event triggered and the error message is :-

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js eval failed twice:(function(){ var e = document.querySelector("select[name=cars]"); var t = "Opel"; for (var i = 0; i < e.options.length; ++i) if (e.options[i].value === t) { e.options[i].selected = true; e.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')) } })(), error: [type: MAP, value: {type=object, subtype=error, className=TypeError, description=TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')
```

Comment: depending on what kind of JS is on your page, there are many reasons. ui automation is hard, so the only advice I have is to figure this out, quite likely that some event should be triggered on the element my guess is`change` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324400/143475

Comment: Yes. Change event is triggered. Also I checked those answers, can't get the things done. Can you please answer here.

Comment: sorry I have nothing more to add here, I can try if you follow this process, basically we need to replicate this else we can keep guessing: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: `mouse()` can work better for JS driven drop-downs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76623198/143475