# Karate UI locate a drop down list<select> with no unique id, class, name

Tags: karate

I am trying to test a dropdown list using karate.
The ID is dynamic(changes every time you load).
The class is used on 3 other dropdown list.
It has no name.
Its title is used on every dropdown list.

**This is what I am given**

```
\<select id="field-:r3t:" required="" aria-required="true" 
class="chakra-select css-65cg11"\>\<option value="" disabled="" 
selected=""\>Select a condition\</option\>
\<option value="New"\>New\</option\>\<option value="Used"\>Used\
</option\>\<option value="Broken"\>Broken\</option\>\</select\>
```

I first tried to `select('#field-:r3t:','New')` which failed because the ID changes every load.

I then tried to `select(.css-65cg11','New')` which passed but because it is not the first drop down using that class, it did not change the selection for the drop down I wanted to test.

Lastly I tried to `select('{}Select a condition', 'New')` which failed

Comment: selects are tricky when they are JS. read comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74473859/143475

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by passing in the full xpath instead of trying to find by a specific attribute