# Chosing an option from a react Select control and trigger change event

Tags: karate

I have a reactJs page which has 3 select controls. On page load only the first select is enabled and populated with items. The second select control is disabled but populated with items. The third select control is disabled but not populated with items.

When I chose a item from the first select, the second select is enabled.

When I chose a item from the second select, a call is triggered and the third select is populated and enabled.

Within the html there is are no 'onchange' details on any of the select controls.

I have been able to chose the item from the first select control using

`* select(select-control1-locator, 'item1')`

however, this does not cause the second select to become enabled.

I did try to trigger the change event manually with:

`* select(select-control1-locator, 'item1').script("_.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true}))")`

while this worked to enable the second select control, when I tried it to do the same with the second select control it caused an internal error.

I have tried to automate the clicking the controls but that isn't working either.

I was able to automate this with Cypress but the test pack uses Karate framework.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mouse()` should work better for these cases. There is a section in the docs specific to this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#drop-downs

If you are still stuck, try to provide a live example of the page you are trying to test or follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test

Comment: I tried the 'mouse()' option which allowed to click the control but doesn't work to select one of the option.

Comment: @ALyon sorry I can't help with the lack of information

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck at select second tab of 2 tabs(in angular application) also,Please let me know if you find a solution. thank you
A tab list of 2 tabs,1 tab is enabled, another is disabled.
Tried
mouse(..).move(..).click()  mouse(..).submit().click() waitFor(..).click()