# Click and Double Click Not Working on Ag Grid Cell

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, karate, ag-grid-angular, mouseclick-event

I am using Karate to interact with an Ag Grid, and I'm facing an issue where the click and double click actions are not working on a specific cell in the grid. I have the following code snippet to click on the cell, but it doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
* waitFor("//div[@row-index='0']//descendant::div[@col-id='status' and @role='gridcell']").highlight()
* locate("//div[@row-index='0']//descendant::div[@col-id='status' and @role='gridcell']").click()
```

I have verified that the element is correctly located using the waitFor and locate commands, and the highlight function shows the element being highlighted. However, the click action does not seem to have any effect. There are no error messages in the console.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue while interacting with Ag Grid using Karate?

when trying to click on a cell within the grid to open a new page.

Comment: see if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76698661/143475 - if you are still stuck, please provide a sample that others can access (see the discussion in the link) and then people will be able to help you