# Karate UI - passing value to a called UI feature

Tags: karate

I found a few answers about using values/variables inside the test. Meaning:

```
* def state = 'NY'
...
And input('#state', state)
```

This works great *within* the feature file.

I need to be able to `* call read` and pass a value to the feature.

so my test will be

```
Feature:

  Background:
    * call read('classpath:util/UI_login.feature')

  Scenario: Create Unit test feature
#   API test -> Create and store name value
    * def create = call read('classpath:create.feature')
    * def name = create.response.name

#   UI test -> use name value to update record
    * call read('classpath:UI/updateRecord.feature') { name: '#(name)' }
```

the `updateRecord.feature` looks like

```
Feature: update record
  Background:
    * def city = 'New York City'
    * def state = 'NY'

  Scenario: update record for specific name value via the ui
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }
    Given driver URLBase + '/update'
    And select('#user--name', name).click()
    And input('#city', city)
    And input('#state', state)
```

it finds the dropdown with class `user--name`, but isn't able to find the name value.

If I hard code the name value like

```
And select('#user--name', 'Hassan').click()
```

The test passes, but I am trying to make this integrate with the other feature files

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the select() does not support variables (Please correct me if I'm wrong!)

I was able to get it to work by doing the following:

call the feature as above ( `* call read('classpath:UI/updateRecord.feature') { name: '#(name)' }` ) and pass the variable the same way.

in the updateRecord.feature, I changed the `And select('#user--name', name).click()` line to:

```
    * mouse('#user--name').click()
    And input('#user--name', name)
```

`#user--name` is a dropdown, but sending the name variable as input works to select it from the list.

Comment: most likely it was not a `select` HTML element. so what you have done looks right to me. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76698661/143475