# locate("element").parent.children[1].click() not working in karate ui automation

Tags: karate, ui-automation

Hi I am trying click and submit the first child of a dynamic drop down and after it's submission  one more button should appear. But I am assuming that the dropdown element is not submitting and hence the new button is not appearing.

Below is the code:

- click("#button1")
- waitFor("#listbox1")
- locate("#listbox1").parent.children[1].click()
- waitFor("button2")  ------> code breaking at this part
- click("#button2")

Comment: sorry, UI automation is hard and every UI is different. if you really want others to help, do something like this (see comments under question): https://stackoverflow.com/q/76680593/143475

Comment: Hey actually that is my office's work. And due to some policy I cant share anything open on internet. But my problem is almost similar as that mentioned questions

Comment: saying it is "almost similar" does not help at all. please note that the link above shows how the team created a sample HTML without sharing their actual / official code. it is up to you now