# how to escape special characters in Karate UI Locators

Tags: karate

I have a input text field with a below tag.
<input id = "searchForm:userName",....>

When i tried to do input("#searchForm:userName", "karate"), its not able to identity the locators.

I believe it's due to the colon(:) in the id value. I have solved the same scenario with other locator type in different locations. But for this one there are no alternate locators to use for this input tag.
Can you please suggest how to overcome this scenario?

Comment: for this I strongly suggest you contribute code to karate to make it better for everyone (or team up with someone to do so) do you have a sample web-site where this can be replicated ?

Comment: hi @PeterThomas, This case I have observed in vendor product deployed in my work environment which cannot be accessible outside the network. I will see any website in public domain have the same scenario in public website to share. Thanks!

Comment: just create a jsfiddle, see how others have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76698661/143475