Switch the focus to Modal dialog box and perform the actions on top of it
We have a scenario to navigate the focus from parent browser window to modal dialog box which is opened after click the add button.
Inside of this dialog box we have an option to enter text in couple of text fields and click the submit button.
Dialog, SwitchPage, SwitchFrame options i have tried and not working. This is one of the common scenario in webui or mobile testing


this is impossible to troubleshoot without access to the actual app, but my guess seeing the image is that all the elements you need to access are in the "normal" dom and usual karate locators would work. if you really need help, try to help others simulate the issue - look at this for example (and read the comments) https://stackoverflow.com/q/76680593/143475
