# Change javascript VAR value with HTML select

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I want to change the value of a variable via a HTML select prompt but it's not working.

```js
// starting number of brick rows
const BRICK_ROWS = document.getElementById('nivel');
```

```html
<select id='nivel' onchange='BRICK_ROWS()'>
  <option value="1">easy</option>
  <option value="2">medium</option>
  <option value="3">hard</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have any other codes inside `BRICK_ROWS()`?

Comment: No, that's it..

Comment: Please add details and clarity to your question for anyone to be able to help you, what do you want to achieve, how are you trying to achieve this, what results are you getting. at a first glance I can tell you directly as it is right now BRICK_ROWS is not a function and if a variable is meant to be changed to define it as a `const` use `let`, I would recommend going through a tutorial about the basics of javascript

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tips! I've changed it to let and it still doesn't updates based on my select value.

Comment: I see here got a similar solution to your question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329978/change-selects-option-and-trigger-events-with-javascript), please have a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change <select>'s option and trigger events with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329978/change-selects-option-and-trigger-events-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

First: you can`t declare a const and then change this value. You should declare a var or let.
Then to get select value:

```
<select id="nivel" onchange="changeValue(event)">
  <option value="1">easy</option>
  <option value="2">medium</option>
  <option value="3">hard</option>
</select>
<script>
  var brickRowsValue = 0
  function changeValue(event) {
    brickRowsValue = event.target.value
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually change the value when the option is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a non-constant variable to store the value:

```js
let difficulty; // you can give it a default value if you want
```

Then, use `.addEventListener()` to listen for changes and update your variable:

```js
const difficultySelector = document.getElementById('nivel');
difficultySelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
    difficulty = difficultySelector.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a some syntax and logical error in your code.

1. `const` declaration mean that you can't change the value through
   your code once you set it.
2. you're trying to call `variable` lie a function using 'onChange'
   event

**The solution:**

3. declare your variable as a `dynamic` variable
4. create a function to reset its value

```js
let BRICK_ROWS = 0;
function SET_BRICK_ROWS() {
BRICK_ROWS = document.getElementById('nivel').value; 
console.log(BRICK_ROWS)
}
```

```html
 <select id='nivel'  onchange='SET_BRICK_ROWS()'>
        <option value="1">easy</option>
        <option value="2">medium</option>
        <option value="3">hard</option>
      </select>
```

**Note:** You can use `addEventListener` If you want a better solution