# Unable to click on "Select" element using JS, nothing appears

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to click on time interval select option on the website Costco, since I am building automation, I am selecting each time interval one by one using JS.
But I've tried multiple solutions but nothing appears when I click on "Select" element using JS, Iw ould like to know any possible solution that may help me, as Iterating over each time interval and selecting each of the receipt is must requirement for this project.
Thank you in advance

**bold**
What I have tried

````
// Dispatch change event

  var simulateMouseEvent = function (
            element,
            eventName,
            coordX,
            coordY
          ) {
            element.dispatchEvent(
              new MouseEvent(eventName, {
                view: window,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                clientX: coordX,
                clientY: coordY,
              })
            );
          };

          var elementToClick = document.getElementById("Showing");

          var box = elementToClick.getBoundingClientRect(),
            coordX = box.left + (box.right - box.left) / 2,
            coordY = box.top + (box.bottom - box.top) / 2;
          simulateMouseEvent(elementToClick, "click", coordX, coordY);
    ```
````

Comment: https://www.costco.com/myaccount/#/app/[GENERATEDI]/ordersandpurchases
--> In-warehouse purchases

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you are trying to do. By chance, what you're wanting to do is just perform a CLICK on the SELECT component? only that?

Comment: @TalesBorn yeah but im clicking on that select component so the dropdown appears and I select any particular timeinterval or option, but the dropdown is not being appeared when I click on the select element.

Comment: @Frosty why do you want to do this? wouldn't it be easier just to set the value in the select?

Comment: @TalesBorn Setting the value doesn't updates the tab below, every option is associated with list of receipts, if I manually select particular option from .value , it doesn't refreshes the receipts due to which I want the dropdown to open and then somehow click on option from there so the receipts refreshes.

Comment: Is it an actual "select" element or is is something else?

Comment: @epascarello yeah actual JS select element but nothing happens when you click on it through JS, which is very strange from JS perspective

Comment: so select the value and fire the change event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329978/change-selects-option-and-trigger-events-with-javascript

Comment: exactly, as @epascarello commented

Comment: @epascarello Life savior, thank you so much!